# Batch files executed from shortcut

Tags: windows, batch-file

On Windows 7 Ultimate, I have a batch file that enables and turns on services related to vmWare workstation. Since the batch file is in the path, I can execute it from the command line in any directory, it works fine.
However when I try to run the batch file from the Windows Explorer (double click) or from a shortcut to the batch file it does not work; for example a typical SC command generates this error:

**

> C:\Batch>sc config      VMwareHostd             start= demand
>  [SC]
>   ChangeServiceConfig
>  FAILED 5:
>
> Access is denied.
>   **

Any ideas? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like a permissions error.  Have you tried running explorer as administrator?

Comment: Either right-click and do 'Run as Administrator', or turn off UAC.

Comment: Don't turn off UAC. Do use right-click and "Run as Administrator".